# Worklabor during construction of Solomon's palace?

Tags: israel, solomon

I am curious about non-Israelites employed in building of Solomon's palace?

Was it common to use such non-Israeli force, especially in position of foreman?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about and what's on-topic here, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394) and: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Do you have a scriptural reference that ties non-Israelite labor to the construction of Solomon's palace?  If you do, please include it in the question to improve the question.  As Lee said, Welcome! :-)

Comment: Your question would appear to be a better fit for the Biblical Hermeneutics SE site.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, from scripture alone I think we can deduce Solomon used both 'Israeli' and 'non-Israeli' workers as both forced labor (employees) and salves.

As far as the Hebrew labor force I would say that since Ahishar was in charge of the palace (though at this time it would not have been built) and Adoniram in charge of the of the labor force, the probability that Hebrew's would have filled 'foreman' positions is high.  Since this still was an issue after Solomons death, and it took another 14 years to build the palace, it's likely that it was not constrained to only the temple.

> 1 Kings 4:6
>   Ahishar was in charge of the palace; and Adoniram the son of Abda was in charge of the forced labor.
>
> 1 Kings 12:18
>   Then King Rehoboam sent Adoram, who was taskmaster over the forced labor, and all Israel stoned him to death with stones. And King Rehoboam hurried to mount his chariot to flee to Jerusalem.
>
> 1 Kings 12:9
>   And he said to them, “What do you advise that we answer this people who have said to me, ‘Lighten the yoke that your father put on us’?”
>
> 1 Kings 12:14
>   he spoke to them according to the counsel of the young men, saying, “My father made your yoke heavy, but I will add to your yoke. My father disciplined you with whips, but I will discipline you with scorpions.”
>
> 1 Kings 9:20-22
>   All the people who were left of the Amorites, the Hittites, the Perizzites, the Hivites, and the Jebusites, who were not of the people of Israel— their descendants who were left after them in the land, whom the people of Israel were unable to devote to destruction—these Solomon drafted to be slaves, and so they are to this day.....